# Clone excisting main HDD to new raid 1 SSD array

Tags: raid, software-raid

I am currently running Ubuntu server on my main server at my homelab. As for now the main drive that contains everything is just an old 250gb HDD I pulled out from an workstation in 2007. Everything works perfectly but this week it started making some funny sounds so it is time to raid 1 before it is too late. I have bought 2 new 250gb SSDs and I would like to:

1. Setup a software raid 1 array using the 2 SSDs.
2. Do an exact clone of the whole HDD onto the new raid 1
3. Reboot server and remove HDD and everything should run off the raid 1 array

I have some experience with btrfs and array concepts in general but I am really confused about the partitions, GRUB(?) etc. so much going on. My HDD got the following partitions as of now:

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
sdc                                                                                                      
├─sdc1                                                                                                   
├─sdc2                    ext4                     ef0a29cc-...    711.8M    20% /boot
└─sdc3                    LVM2_member              RcHJGi-...                
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4                     87a8bc3b-...       81G    24% /
```